# how would the bot display a different message depending on the person who typed the command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am new to discord.js and want to know how I would make the bot say something different depending on the `${message.author}`.

For example:

```
Person 1: !hello
Bot: Nope, goodbye.
Person 2: !hello
Bot: Oh, hello!
```

My command handler has this sort of thing in the main/index.js:

```
    if(command === 'hello'){
        client.commands.get('hello').execute(message, args);
```

and in a JS file called "hello", it has this:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'hello',
    description: 'example message',
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send(`example`);
    }
}
```

If the bot could check who is typing in this sort of format, that would be really useful, thanks. Sorry for my lack of understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the author's [id](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=id), [tag](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=tag), etc. If it's the one you're looking for, send a message with hello, if not, say goodbye:

```js
execute(message, args) {
  if (message.author.tag === 'hydrabolt#0001')
    return message.channel.send(`Hello, ${message.author}!`);
  return message.channel.send('Nope, goodbye!');
}
```

```js
execute(message, args) {
  if (message.author.id === '844191247870591006')
    return message.channel.send(`Hello, ${message.author}!`);
  return message.channel.send('Nope, goodbye!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the documentation https://discord.js.org :)
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message for `Message`,
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember for `GuildMember` (a member in a guild),
and https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User for `User`.

```
execute(message, args) {
  message.channel.send(`Hello ${message.author.tag}`);
}
```

This would return `Hello user#0001`.

```
execute(message, args) {
  switch(message.author.tag) {
    case 'person1#0001':
      message.channel.send(`Nope, goodbye.`);
      break;
    case 'person2#0002':
      message.channel.send(`Oh, hello!`)
      break;
   default:
      message.channel.send(`Hello, ${message.author.tag}!`)
      break;
}
```

If the author is person1, the bot will reply "Nope, goodbye."
If it's person2, the bot will reply "Oh, hello!"
And if it's another person, the bot will reply "Hello, user#0001" (with the tag of the user)